# How to get the path of a exe file in AWS layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf with a lambda. I create a zip file with the structure and make an layer.

wkhtmltopdf.zip

```
├───bin
├───fonts
│   └───dejavu
└───lib
```

where wkhtmltopdf.exe is in the bin folder. My code,

```
pdfconf = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=os.getenv('PATH')+"/wkhtmltopdf.exe")
```

The error message,

> No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Try `/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`

Comment: `AWS` runs `Linux/Unix` and it may not have emulator `WINE` to run `.exe` files for `Windows`.

Comment: `PATH` keeps list of folders which system uses to search executable - it is NOT single path - so using it with `+ "/wkhtmltopdf.exe"` create totally wrong path. You should rather use `Current Working Directory` - `os.getcwd() + "/wkhtmltopdf.exe"` - or use path to running code `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/wkhtmltopdf.exe"`

Comment: @jellycsc you are a life saver! Your solution worked for me! Thanks! May you answer so I can accept ?

Comment: @furas apparently lambda lets you use any binary and wkhtmltopdf has a separate version that can be used in lambda. Thanks for your suggestion. I will do some more research about how path works when there are multiple layers. Cheers!  
 https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OP's comment, the correct path should be `/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`.